# Finding the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\nu=m_\alpha$ be the Borel measure on $\Bbb R$ that is generated by the increasing function
$$\alpha(x)=\begin{cases} 
   x & \text{if } x<0 \\
   x+1       & \text{if } x \geq 0
  \end{cases}$$
and let $\mu$ be the Cantor measure. Find the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$.

**Attempt.** I will try to mimic the proof of Lebesgue decomposition theorem. So, let $\theta=\mu+\nu$. Then $\mu\ll\theta$. By the Radon-Nikodym theorem, there is a nonnegative measurable function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ such that $\mu(E)=\int_E fd\theta$ for any Borel set $E\in\Bbb R$. Define $X_{ab}=\{x\in\Bbb R: f(x)>0\}$ and $X_{sin}=\{x\in\Bbb R: f(x)=0\}$, $\nu_{ab}(E)=\nu(E\cap X_{ab})$ and $\nu_{sin}(E)=\nu(E\cap X_{sin})$ for any Borel set $E\in \Bbb R$. Then it is easy to check that $\nu=\nu_{ab}+\nu_{sin}$, $\nu_{ab}\ll \mu$ and $\nu_{sin}\perp\mu$. So, it remains to find what $f$ is.

Since $\mu$ is the Cantor measure, we have $F(x)=\mu([0,x])=\int_0^{x}fd\theta=\int_0^{x}fd\mu+\int_0^{x}fd\nu$ for any $x\in \Bbb [0,1]$, where $F:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is the Cantor-Lebesgue function.

I don't know how to go further from here. Thanks!

Comment: Are the two measures $\mu, \nu$ singular?

Comment: Yes, they are singular since $\nu(\mathcal{C})=0=\mu(\Bbb R - \mathcal{C})$ where $F$ is defined on $\Bbb R$. Thank you!

Comment: Lebesgue decomposition has two parts: absolutely continuous part and singular part.  It is usually best to first find the singular part.